# accessing deeply nested params rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters, nested-attributes

I am writing a piece of code in my controller that is suposed to take the data a user inputs in the form of 00:00 and convert that into minutes before sending it to the model. The code I am using is pretty simple, just split the :duration parameter at the colon and multiply hours by 60 and add the minutes to that number. When I submit the for I get an error when it tries to perform split on a nil object. This must mean I am not accessing the parameter correctly but I am confused as to how I would navigate to a deeply nested parameter and cant seem to find any documentation regarding deeply nested parameters.

Here is my model organization:

```
log_entry >>
has many
workouts >>
has many 
workout_times, which has :duration as an attribute
```

This is the code within my log_entries_controller:

```
def convert_duration
  hours, minutes = params[:log_entry][:workout][:workout_time][:duration].split(":")
  params[:log_entry][:workout][:workout_time][:duration] = (hours.to_i * 60 + minutes.to_i)
end
```

I have tried all the ways I could think of to write the params part but I cants seem to get it right. I am pretty new to rails/programming so there might be somthing totally obvious I am missing...

EDIT

Here is the log info of parameters past:

```
Parameters: {
  "commit" => "Save",
  "log_entry" => {
    "date(1i)" => "2011",
    "date(2i)" => "10",
    "date(3i)" => "13",
    "workouts_attributes" => {
      "0" => {
        "time_of_day" => "AM",
        "summary" => "",
        "workout_times_attributes" => {
          "0" => {
            "duration" => "2:00",
            "zone" => "1",
            "_destroy" => "false"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "authenticity_token"=>"zD6qS6jOSQ3/mRyH7RAgAzWYmwHub0+uBG1sjPVvkEY=",
  "utf8"=>"\342\234\223"
}
```

Comment: Added info to post, it looks like the structure I was expecting..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just assign the parameter you want to your model like so:

```
def save
  workout = Workout.new(params[:workout])
  workout.workout_time.duration = convert_duration(workout)  
end
```

Then in your convert_duration method do:

```
def convert_duration(workout)
  hours, minutes = workout.workout_time.duration.split(":")
  (hours.to_i * 60 + minutes.to_i)
end
```

In Ruby the last statement of a method is returned, so this would return your calculated duration back to the save method which will set the duration on the workout_time object for the workout object we created from the parameters passed to the method.

Comment: Do you mean put that in the controller? I tried replacing my convert_duration function with this but it didn't seem to effect what was stored in database at all:     `def convert_duration
      workout = Workout.new(params[:workout])
      workout.workout_times.each do |time|
      hours, minutes = time.split(":")
      time = (hours.to_i * 60 + minutes.to_i)
    end`

Comment: The reason I am doing this in the controller is when I try to adjust the :duration in the model it seems to have already converted the hours to an integer and dropped the rest, causing 03:23 to turn into 3. This is why I am trying to do the logic in the controller before the model gets to it.

Comment: I've modified my answer so that it might be more clear.  You basically assign the params to a new Workout object, and you can pass that object to the convert_duration method, which gives you access to the items you need.

Comment: I added those mothods and initially it was throwing an error of no workout_time method for workout, I corrected it by rewriting it to accept multiple workout_times, passing each duration to the `convert_duration()` function. This still doesnt seem to work though and I actually dont really understand how creating a new Workout object would effect the outcome since the model is looking for the Log_Entry object passed by the create method containing the deeply nested attributes. Can't I can simply access the duration parameters before they are passed to the model using my before_filter?

Comment: your params are the data for your objects, that's why doing something like Log_Entry.new(params[:log_entry] works if the parameters your passing match those of the object. If you're Log_Entry, Workout and Workout_Time models don't match what you're passing via your params, you're only complicating your life. Assigning the params to an object allows you to access the data via the model rather than doing the long list of params like you have in your example in your original post. It's much easier to do workout.workout_time.duration than params[:log_entry][:workout][:workout_time][:duration]

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying, when I do that I run into a problem when it throws an error `private method 'split' called for 3:Fixnum` From what I gather researching this, the model is getting ahold of the parameters and converting all the parameters to their respective data types. For example 3:30 would be converted from the string "3:30" back to an integer, 3 dropping the minutes side and therefore throwing the error when the split method is called on it. This is why I need to some how intercept that parameter before the model manages to adjust it...

Comment: Rather than trying to do a bunch of extra work to intercept something so you can manipulate the data, change the data that is passed to be more in line with what you expect to se in the DB. For example, you could create a Duration object, that takes hours and minutes as individual integers and set your Workout_Times model to ```has_one => :duration``` with the data in the form that's easier to manipulate you'll write a whole lot less code and get the data you want.

Comment: Thanks Koby! Ya I guess that would be the best approach to take, I find it weird that there isnt a simple way to adjust the parameters before they get to the model but maybe my situation is unique. Thanks for your help! Do you have any idea why my first approach didnt work, was I maybe navigating the parameter tree wrong?

Comment: The only thing I can venture to guess is that duration is nil because of the fact that in your params list you're doing stuff like ```:workout``` and ```:workout_time```, but the actual params are named ```:workout_attributes``` and ```:workout_time_attributes```, because that's how they're being passed from the ```form_for``` on the view.  If this was my code, that'd be the first thing I'd check.